# Error while using running chat application in CodeIgniter 4

Tags: php, codeigniter, codeigniter-4

Downloaded a git repo for a chat application using the below link

[Git Repo for Chat Application](https://github.com/alexlancer/Codeigniter-4-Chat-Tutorial)

Then changed the env file to .env file and also uncommented default database block as shown below.

```
 database.default.hostname = localhost
 database.default.database = chat
 database.default.username = root
 database.default.password = 
 database.default.DBDriver = MySQLi
```

Then opened terminal and executed this command `php spark migrate`

But while executing this error pops up

```
PS C:\xampp\htdocs\Codeigniter-4-Chat-Tutorial> php spark migrate
PHP Warning:  require(C:\xampp\htdocs\Codeigniter-4-Chat- 
Tutorial\app\Config/../../vendor/codeigniter4/framework/system/bootstrap.php): failed to 
open stream: No such file or directory in C:\xampp\htdocs\Codeigniter-4-Chat-Tutorial\spark on line 44

Warning: require(C:\xampp\htdocs\Codeigniter-4-Chat- 
Tutorial\app\Config/../../vendor/codeigniter4/framework/system/bootstrap.php): failed to open 
stream: No such file or directory in C:\xampp\htdocs\Codeigniter-4-Chat-Tutorial\spark on line 44
PHP Fatal error:  require(): Failed opening required 'C:\xampp\htdocs\Codeigniter-4-Chat- 
Tutorial\app\Config/../../vendor/codeigniter4/framework/system/bootstrap.php' 
(include_path='C:\xampp\php\PEAR') in C:\xampp\htdocs\Codeigniter-4-Chat-Tutorial\spark on line 44

Fatal error: require(): Failed opening required 'C:\xampp\htdocs\Codeigniter-4-Chat- 
Tutorial\app\Config/../../vendor/codeigniter4/framework/system/bootstrap.php' 
(include_path='C:\xampp\php\PEAR') in C:\xampp\htdocs\Codeigniter-4-Chat-Tutorial\spark on line 44
PS C:\xampp\htdocs\Codeigniter-4-Chat-Tutorial>
```

How to resolve this? Any help appreciated.

Comment: Did you run the command - composer install ?

Comment: I think you forgot installing the composer installation

Answer (score 1):

It looks to me that you didn't run the composer update command after starting the project. So in this case your vendor folder is probably missing a lot of files.

Go to the root of your project in the terminal and run:

```
$ composer update
```

And you should be fine.